# Listar las etiquetas a las que hice Sugerencias/Crearlas/Editarlas pendientes de aprobación

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, interfaz-de-usuario

Como verán en mi perfil, en el área de etiquetas se ven las etiquetas con las que he interactuado haciendo preguntas o respuestas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si entro en *Todas las Acciones*, se ven las Sugerencias, pero no veo en qué estado están:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en la imagen, aquí se muestran todas, incluyendo las aprobadas y las que no están aún aprobadas.

***Mi Pregunta:***

¿Cómo puedo listar las etiquetas a las que hice Sugerencias/Crearlas/Editarlas pendientes de aprobación (no aprobadas) ***únicamente***, ya que esta tabla de datos no tiene un filtro?

Comment: si sale "sugerido" a secas es que aún no ha sido revisado por suficiente gente. Si se aprueba sale "aprobar" (_aprobada_ sería mejor traducción) y si se rechaza lo indica con "rejected" en inglés (no sé cómo se ha traducido al castellano).

Comment: como filtrar cada una de esas opciones???

Comment: Posiblemente con SEDE (véase [tag:data-explorer]) pero también podrías usar JavaScript/CSS directamente en la consola del navegador o si es algo que vas a usar continuamente mediante una extensión del navegador

Comment: Estaba pensando hacer webscrap ... con javascript, ya que el objetivo seria extraer la informacion de la tabla he incorporarla en un datatable.net con la herramienta de busqueda que asi permita un filtrado, pero como que se me escapa de las manos ... ya que SE , SOes no incorpora la herramienta... XD